# Loading multiple images simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

I am trying to load images at the same time in React.js.

I tried a lot but still not able to figure out, how to do it.

1. This is the first thing, I tried to load images normally.

```js
class MultipleImageExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageOneUrl: `https://picsum.photos/id/${parseInt(
        Math.random() * 1000,
        10
      )}/400.jpg`,
      imageTwoUrl: `https://picsum.photos/id/${parseInt(
        Math.random() * 1000,
        10
      )}/400.jpg`,
      imageOneLoaded: false,
      imageTwoLoaded: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      h1 > Multiple Image Example < /h1> <
      img src = {
        this.state.imageOneUrl
      }
      style = {
        {
          objectFit: "cover",
          width: "312px",
          height: "216px"
        }
      }
      alt = "image1" /
      >
      <
      img src = {
        this.state.imageTwoUrl
      }
      style = {
        {
          objectFit: "cover",
          width: "312px",
          height: "216px"
        }
      }
      alt = "image2" /
      >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < MultipleImageExample / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

2. This is the load event, I have attached to the img tag.

```js
class MultipleImageExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageOneUrl: `https://picsum.photos/id/${parseInt(
        Math.random() * 1000,
        10
      )}/400.jpg`,
      imageTwoUrl: `https://picsum.photos/id/${parseInt(
        Math.random() * 1000,
        10
      )}/400.jpg`,
      imageOneLoaded: false,
      imageTwoLoaded: false
    };
  }

  handleImage1Load = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, imageOneLoaded: true });
  };

  handleImage2Load = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, imageTwoLoaded: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Multiple Image Example</h1>
        <img
          src={this.state.imageOneUrl}
          style={{ objectFit: "cover", width: "312px", height: "216px" }}
          alt="image1"
          onLoad={this.handleImage1Load}
        />
        <img
          src={this.state.imageTwoUrl}
          style={{ objectFit: "cover", width: "312px", height: "216px" }}
          alt="image2"
          onLoad={this.handleImage2Load}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MultipleImageExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**I am still confused, how I can show loaded images together.**

Please help on this. This is the sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-5f71p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your second approach, and hide an image until the other has loaded, here's a working sandbox link (based on your link): https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3iblh

e.g. for the first image, you handle visibility based on state:
`visiblity: this.state.imageTwoLoaded ? "visible" : "hidden"`